# Guess maximal solution of ODE ($y^{'} = X(t,y) = \frac 1 3 y^{1/4} + t^{1/3}$) on the form $y(t) = at^p$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following ODE: $y^{'} = X(t,y) = \frac 1 3 y^{1/4} + t^{1/3}$ defined on $D_X = (0, \infty) \times (0,\infty)$.

I want to guess a maximal solution of the form $y(t) = at^p$ for $a,p \in \mathbb R$.

However, inserting $y(t)$ into the equation above, I get: $apt^{p-1} = \frac 1 3 (at^p)^{1/4} + t^{1/3}$.

But I can't find parameters $a,p$ such that the equation is valid ?

Can someone help ?

Comment: why $p = 4/3, a = 1$ don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the same power of $t$, you need $p-1=p/4=1/3$, i.e. $p=4/3$.

Factoring $t^{1/3}$ out, you will get the equation
$$
4a/3=a^{1/4}/3+1
$$
for $a$. One solution is $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose $\displaystyle p-1=\frac{p}{4}=\frac{1}{3}$... what then?